# Issue Ingesting json in Powershell

Tags: reactjs, json, powershell, api, sharepoint

I am trying to send an API request to a backend Azure function and I am having a mental block.
In the past I've had no problem reading from a local .json file in the azure function itself.

So this is an example of what I am trying to send:

```
{"requestType":"CommSite"}
```

In the react app I am doing this:

```
fetchRequest = () => {
    console.log ("submitting request");
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'requestType':'CommSite'
    })
```

The function errors out when I try to read the body of the request.

```
     $requestBody = $Request.Body
    $requestType = $Request.Body.requestType.ToUpper().Trim()
```

If I print out the body of the payload I can see that it comes over:

```
{"requestType":"CommSite"}
```

What do I need to do at this point to access the individual elements?  I tried ConvertFrom-Json (as I do when reading from files) but that also blows up.  Do I need to change how I am assembling the body in the call from client side?

Comment: “The function errors out” - what’s the error message?

Comment: Ah, sorry - I meant to fill that in.  If I change the code to this:   $requestBody = $Request.Body | ConvertFrom-Json
.   The json in the service now looks like this.
@{requestType=CommSite;}

Before I was referencing the body directly.  I am a little backwards now - should I change how I convert it on the client side or do something different in the service?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by an issue that I actually caused myself.  When I was working with this I was getting CORS errors.  Because I didn't want to solve that problem at the time I commented out the header and this included "application/json".  This resulted in the content coming over as text and not json even though it looked like json.

I went back and solved the cors issue by allowing for the origin in the the function app that I was calling and all was well in my code.